# Specifing more than 1 XmlRoot attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net, deserialization

I have a class used for storing deserialized XML data. I want to make this class backward compatible so it accepts the old Root element name.

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="cancellation-response")>
Public Class ApplicantResponse
    ' properties go here!
End Class
```

I would like the deserializer to use this class if the root element is either "applicant-response" *or* "cancellation-response".

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="applicant-response")>
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="cancellation-response")>
Public Class ApplicantResponse
    ' properties go here!
End Class
```

Is this possible?

Current Visual Studio complains using the above method:

> Attribute 'XmlRootAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to change settings to Fragment :             XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename",settings);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for me was to pass in the root name dynamically into the XmlSerializer:

```vb
xmlRoot = New XmlRootAttribute(myRootName)  
serializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ApplicantResponse), xmlRoot) 
response = CType(serializer.DeSerialize(New StringReader(serializedResponse)), ApplicantResponse)
```

where myRootName is either "applicant-response" or "cancellation-response".

Comment: This is correct.  You may not specify multiple root element names at the same time because valid XML documents can only have a single root element.  Good job figuring it out!

Comment: Thanks! Just updated the answer to use XmlSerializer directly rather than my helper library. Now I only need to change myRootName as part of a database value or app setting if I need to revert to a previous version.